# Using substitution method solve the recurrence $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3}) + \frac{n}{(\log n)}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, substitution

I try to do it as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119799/solve-the-recurrence-tn-2tn-2n-logn) but since my log is base 3 it doesn´t turn into i

[image of my incomplete attempt to find complexity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aegPS.jpg)

if my n=3^k then my sum´s division is 0, so I must be doing something wtong but idk what.

Comment: In the sum you should have $\log(n/3^i)=\log (n)-i$ and not $\log(n/3^k)$. If you fix that, then you can finish the same way as in the example you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $n=3^m$ and assuming $\log n \equiv \log_3 n$

$$
T\left(3^m\right) = 3T\left(3^{m-1}\right) + \frac{3^m}{m}
$$

making $\mathcal{T}\left(\cdot\right)= T\left(3^{(\cdot)}\right)$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(m\right)=3\mathcal{T}\left(m-1\right)+\frac{3^m}{m}
$$

This is a linear recurrence with solution to the homogeneous

$$
\mathcal{T}_h\left(m\right)=c_03^m
$$

choosing as a particular solution $\mathcal{T}_p(m)= c_m3^m$ after substitution we have

$$
c_m3^m=3c_{m-1}3^{m-1}+\frac{3^m}{m}
$$

so

$$
c_m = c_{m-1}+\frac 1m
$$

and

$$
c_m = H_m
$$

and finally

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(m\right)=(c_0+H_m) 3^m
$$

but $m = \log_3 n$ hence

$$
T(n) = n(c_0+H_{\log_3 n})
$$

Comment: Good answer. Just to finish with non-integer index for harmonic numbers use digamma function $$T(n) =n(c_1+\psi(\log_3n+1))$$ where $c_1=c_0+\gamma$ being $\gamma$ the Euler Mascheroni constant.